# Passing object between views (flash message)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the best way to pass message in the below scenario.

In the success scenario of `$scope.p.$save`, the result contains a message (`res.message`), which I like to display in the next view (`$location.path("/test/"+res.reply.Id)`). Without AngularJS, I may pass it in the url or save it in session cookies. But, I guess there might be a better way in AngularJS as there is no browser redirect and the state should be available. What is the best way to achieve this?

Setting it in rootScope shows it while I use browser back button, and the scope of the message should only for the first navigation to the new view.

```
function NewCtrl(Phone, $location, $rootScope, $scope) {
    $scope.p = new Phone();
    $scope.save = function () {
        $scope.p.$save(
            {},
            function (res) {
                $rootScope.message = res.message **//<-- this will cause message still set when using browser back button, etc**
                $location.path("/test/"+res.reply.Id); **//<-- Req: needs to pass the message to next view**
            }, function (res) {
            //TODO
            }
        );
    };
}
....
PhoneApp.factory('Phone', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/test/:_id')
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use a service which displays the flash on $routeChangeSuccess.

Each time you set a flash message, add it to a queue, and when the route changes take the first item off the queue and set it to the current message.

Here's a demo:

http://plnkr.co/edit/3n8m1X?p=preview

Comment: I just edited it, I thought of a **much** better and simpler implementation, which supports multiple flashes, using an array.

Comment: You may also consider `$routeChangeStart` since success is sometimes (depending on your setup) called too late in the process (the new page may already be loaded and the alert scope resolved).

Comment: This was perfect just wat i was looking for thank you @AndyJoslin

Answer (score 5):

I was looking to implement similar functionality, but actually wanted more of a growl style message.

I've updated the excellent plinkr code that Andy provided above to include a 'pop' method that leverages the [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) growl-style notification library.

My update also lets you to specify the notification type (info, warning, success, error) and title.

The 'pop' method skips adding the message to the queue, and instead pops it up on the screen immediately.  The set/get functionality from Andy's previous plinkr remains mostly unchanged.

You can find my update here: http://plnkr.co/edit/MY2SXG?p=preview

Comment: It's worth noting, if the message object you pass into flash.set() is an ngmodel, it's passed by reference, so multiple entries in the queue will all be clones of the same object.

In other words, if you do something like this:
$scope.msg = {title: 'title', body: 'msg body', type: 'info'};

then have a form using this as its model and pass this scope variable in to set, anything already in the queue will be changed to contain the new values...which kind of defeats the purpose of a message queue ;)

Comment: Your original example had an issue loading the toatr library - I updated the sample and included the toastr script inline: http://plnkr.co/edit/vSWKtv?p=preview

Comment: Thanks.  Something must have changed since I wrote that.. it was loading previously :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to do this default to AngularJS.  Your best bet would just be passing the message (encoded) through a query string.