# In AngularJs, how do I command to change location and show an alert in the new location?

Tags: angularjs

I'll try to be clearer than my question title :)

There a controller+partial for creating some entity, say a contact.
When I hit the save button, I'm able to invoke my custom `save` method on controller.
There I invoke `contactResource.save` (that's my custom resource to talk with REST) with a `success` callback.

In `success` callback I'd like to change location to go to the contact list page, and when contact page is shown I'd like to show an alert to say that everything was fine.

```
function save() {
    contactRepository.save(newContact, function success() {
        // Redirect to view and show toast
        console.log('Success');

        $location.path('/list');
        // DO SOMETHING TO LET THE LIST PAGE SHOW AN ALERT

    }, function error() {
        console.log('Error');
    });
}
```

The only way I can think of, is to create some kind of service to "post" an alert, and the next page showing should check the service for any alert posted, show it and then delete that.

Is there any better/suggested approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm, I didn't thought about looking up for the term 'angularjs *flash message*'.
It seems [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655689/passing-object-between-views-flash-message) has a very good answer. Kudos to Andy Joslin and Will Vincent.